# node js mysqlquery attempting to add .then

Tags: node.js

Currently I'm working on a project in node js.  Specifically I'm using soem boiler plate for adobe CEP which allows you to run some js in a panel in their programs. In the code there is the following code that works fine.

```
mysqlConn.query(query, function(err, result) {
do something with error and result})
```

When this is execute it gives me an error or result depending on if there is data or there was a problem etc. What I need to do is to run another function after this executes and gives me the result.  My knowledge of promises is limited (even thou I've read extensively on it and done tons of tutorials).  In my limited knowledge I assume mysqlConn.query returns a promise.  So I was assuming I can just do this:

```
mysqlConn.query(query, function(err, result) {
    do something with error and result})
.then(console.log('anything here?'));
```

This logs to the console 'anything here?' but it also gives me this error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: mysqlConn.query(...).then is not a function
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how I can achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This indicates the `mysqlConn.query` method does not return a Promise**

Instead, you will need to "promisify" the method so it can be changed with `.then()` and friends:

```
const myFunc = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return mysqlConn.query(query, function(err, result) {
    if (err) reject(err);
    return resolve(result);
  });
});
```

Now we have `myFunc`, a Promise-based interface wrapping the callback-basked `query` function. We can use it like so:

```
return myFunc()
  .then((result) => { ... }) // result will be the result of the query
  .catch((err) => { .. } ) // err from the query as well
```

This can also be achieved in a slightly more involved way through [other tools](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html), but I highly recommend you understand this example first.

Comment: Thank you! One question.  I notice you put return to call the mysqlConn.query and also return to all myFunc() does teh mysqlConn query get called automatically?  and then calling retrun myFunc() doesn't it just get called as "myFunc()" @jakemingolla